# Open and Close Container (div)

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I had my jQuery working earlier but I recently had to add a few more div's to my HTML. I am trying to open and close `discussionContainer` with a click on the button `replyButton`. Any help would be great.

I will be putting an ng-click on the `replyButton` here soon as I will be passing through and id for an http request to grab content from my db, could I do this in Angularjs instead? Maybe some other ideas/suggestions than jQuery and Angularjs? On page load the `discussionContainer` will be closed.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".replyButton", function() {
  $(this).parent('.forQuestions').find(".discussionContainer").slideToggle(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="question">
  <div class="forQuestion">
    <div class="cardBody">
      {{answer.aContent}}
    </div>
    <div class="cardFooter">
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer1">
        <button class="replyButton">Reply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer2">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="controller.deleteAnswer(answer._id)"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="controller.showEditAnswerModal(answer)"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer3">
        {{answer.aDate | date: 'medium'}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="discussionContainer">
      <ul>
        <li>comment1</li>
        <li>comment2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="newComment">
        <textarea rows="2" cols="30" placeholder="New comment"></textarea>
        <button type="button" name="button">Comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is:

**1--** [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) only travels a single level up the DOM tree

**2--** You have no element with class `forQuestions` your correct class is `forQuestion` without `s` on the end .. so you need to use `.closest('.forQuestion')`

Demo

```js
$(document).on("click", ".replyButton", function() {
  $(this).closest('.forQuestion').find(".discussionContainer").slideToggle(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="question">
  <div class="forQuestion">
    <div class="cardBody">
      {{answer.aContent}}
    </div>
    <div class="cardFooter">
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer1">
        <button class="replyButton">Reply</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer2">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="controller.deleteAnswer(answer._id)"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="controller.showEditAnswerModal(answer)"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 footer3">
        {{answer.aDate | date: 'medium'}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="discussionContainer">
      <ul>
        <li>comment1</li>
        <li>comment2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="newComment">
        <textarea rows="2" cols="30" placeholder="New comment"></textarea>
        <button type="button" name="button">Comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to get the rest of it. I was unaware of the `.parent` only travelling up one level and that silly s, that is my mistake for missing that...sorry. But again thank you for the guidance